# Run part of a build script on a windows box and the rest on linux

Tags: command-line, build, windows-services, build-automation

My build script runs on linux and invokes things like gcc, shell scripts, etc.
Part of the solution is written in mono and could be compiled easily on linux.
But I want to obfuscate the code. Not manually, but as part of the build process.

Therefore I need to invoke Dotfuscator and Dotfuscator so far only runs on windows.

Is there a good solutions to invoke command line based workers/build scripts remotely from linux on a windows machine? I don't just want to run a command remotely, but also pass files along.

Like a windows service that is accessed using simple curl-uploads of a tar file, creates a temp folder for each concurrently connected client (or blocks concurrent calls) and unpacks the file, invokes something on these files and packages the result again as tar file to give it back to the caller? And clears the temp file even in case of failures?

Maybe someone knows a good solution that saves me from writing this myself!

It should not be so uncommon that a build process spans multiple platforms, yet common build server answers I found mainly talk about only one build script.
Also think about running e.g. the nsis setup builder from a linux driven build script, if part of your solution has a tiny windows component

Comment: Is it fair game to have Windows shares mounted via CIFS or Linux smbd exports mounted on the Windows machines?

Comment: Basically `tar sources | ssh windows buildscript > obfuscated` provided you have an ssh server running on the Windows box, and can write a build script which doesn't trample its own feet.

Comment: If there are shares mounted, then it becomes tricky to allocate a temp folder name and delete it again, someone has to clean it up. And running a ssh server on windows is not that easy I think

Comment: I shouldn't think it would be that difficult to clean up shared folder when subordinate build completes.  To make it a bit simpler, you could run the Windows build in VM on the Linux machine.

Comment: The Linux build server should not run VMs, that would be too heavy.